# flask container not responding while standalone application works

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

**python**

```
from flask import Flask
import socket    
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

when I run this using **python app.py**, I am able to access it on web browser with http://192.168.56.1:5000/

**Now create a container with docker**

```
# Format: FROM    repository[:version]
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**build and run it.**
    docker build -t helloworld:latest .
    docker run -d -p 5000:5000 helloworld

docker ps -a shows image is up from 7 mins. but when I hit url on web browser, it doesn't respond.

What can be wrong here? any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to expose the port. You can follow this [quick guide](https://www.wintellect.com/containerize-python-app-5-minutes/)

Comment: What do the docker logs say?

Comment: @Terminus, it only says running on 0.0.0.0:5000, press ctrl+c to exit.

Comment: @new-dev-123, tried exposing it too. same behaviour.

Comment: Ran this on my machine, worked fine. Perhaps a firewall issue?

Comment: I got the solution: If you're using Docker Toolbox you'd need to access http://192.168.99.100:5000.